# Uncaught TypeError: moment.defineLocale is not a function in use locale for change calture

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, momentjs

I use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) in `typescript` with `webpack` for create my own java-script client-side component and every things is OK.
Version of used components:

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.2.2",
    "ignore-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.45.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0-beta.3"
  }
```

For add Persian culture like this [example](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/), I must write some code like this:

```js
import * as moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/fa";

console.log(moment.locale()); // en
moment.locale("fa");
console.log(moment.locale()); // muste be fa
```

Now i receive this error :

[image: webpack error in browser]
I think extra process that webpack do over .js file and simulate `require()` method case this problem. I search an find some question like my one, but answers is not usable.what is problem and how can I config webpack for fix this problem.

### UPDATE:

After spend many hours in code. I find out that problem can be fix with this:  For example for Persian culture in related .js setting file replace `../moment` path with `moment`:

[image]

This solution is not god so need help for best way that don't need change in moment source code. I think some things like edit path routing in `tsc` or webpack config can fix this problem. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Did you checked that ? https://github.com/umbraco-community/umbraco-analytics/issues/56

Comment: Thanks @Aaron_Actu for comment but I check that before. not usable

Answer (score 0):

The version of `moment js` support for `moment.locale()` is added  `@ 2.8.0`.

As of v2.8.1, `moment.locale('en')` sets the localization but does not return a `moment`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edit the question